# Why are a lot of the merged UXExchange questions tagged with "untagged"

Tags: discussion, merge

I know that these questions all had tags on the old site (it was required there too), but many do not have tags anymore and are tagged [untagged](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged). Why weren't the tags carried over completely?

Answer (score 2):

When a question is migrated in, any tags that do not exist on the destination site are stripped from the question.  This is done to prevent tags that shouldn't exist being created through a migration backdoor.

Questions that end up without any tags as a result of the migration logic are tagged with [untagged](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) so that the community can review them.

Comment: Is it worth to retag every untagged question? Or should we carefully select some, for example high voted questions or unanswered questions? (As retagged questions get up in activity again..)