# Call to arms - action needed to clean up the [untagged] questions

Tags: support, status-completed, retagging

We still have 15 question that are tagged [untagged](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged). I know some of them may well date from the [merging in of the old SE 1.0 site](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250/why-are-a-lot-of-the-merged-uxexchange-questions-tagged-with-untagged), but then should be really cleaned up by now.

I've made a start, voting to close ones I think are off topic and voting to delete the ones that are already closed, but it's going to need more work to get this sorted.

Comment: I went and tagged 7 of them but some of them don't lend themselves well to tagging (http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5567/have-you-read-this-article-what-was-your-reaction) and some only fit very general tags (testing, interaction design) but I figured that was better than nothing. As for deleting I was never clear when/if something should be deleted as opposed to closed when it's not something clearly abusive.

Comment: Make that 13, I have no idea what to tag the remaining two though, they're just chatty discussion questions. If anyone knows how to tag them go ahead.

Comment: @BenBrocka I've closed the remaining two. I don't see any reason to keep those questions. If there are no objections, I'll go ahead and delete them.

Comment: They don't look constructive or well suited to this site's format, no objections from me.

Comment: Done. There are no more untagged questions. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

This is now complete.

(we like to have answers on these so they don't show up as no answers..)